# Enter button error in java swing

Tags: java, swing, converters

I'm doing a programming exercise.
Miles and kilometer converter.(both case)

However, If I input number and press "Enter", nothing happened. 
I don't know what part I need to modify... :(
Help me please..

```
public class Grid1 extends JFrame{
    private JLabel label1,label2;

    private JTextField textField1,textField2;

    private Container container;

    private GridLayout grid1;

    // set up GUI

    public Grid1(){
        super( "Miles to Km / Km to Mile" );

        grid1 = new GridLayout( 2, 2 );

        container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout( grid1 );

        label1 = new JLabel("Mile");

        container.add(label1);

        textField1 = new JTextField("");

        container.add( textField1 );

        label2 = new JLabel("Kilometer"); 

        container.add(label2);

        textField2 = new JTextField( "" );

        container.add( textField2 );

        TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();

        textField1.addActionListener(handler);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        submit.addActionListener(handler);

        setSize(300, 100);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            float miles = 0, km = 0;

            String string = "";

            if(event.getSource() == textField1){
                string = "textField1: " + event.getActionCommand();

                km = miles * 1.609344f;
            }else if(event.getSource() == textField2){
                string = "textField2: " + event.getActionCommand();

                miles = km / 1.609344f; 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String args[]){
        Grid1 application = new Grid1();

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}  // end class GridLayoutDemo
```

Comment: You aren't assigning the converted result to any text box, thus nothing on the screen will change. Also, if the `ActionEvent` was triggered by a Submit button, the event source will not be textField1 or textField2.

Comment: Finally, I find and make sure. If I put mile and press Enter, the output is kilometer. other side too. However, when I put the kilometer, the changing mile is wrong. Can you tell me what's wrong? I put the textField1.addActionListener(new TextFieldHandler(){ }); textField2.addActionListener(new TextFieldHandler(){ }); next to container.add( textField2 ); line.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove handler from variable `textField1` if you need to update data from button click. And in handler class you shold store data into result field/label.
In your case it looks like:

```
private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        // In both cases you should get value from textField,
        // parse it and store computed values in another field
        float miles = 0, km = 0;

        try {
            if(event.getSource() == textField1){
                // Value form field stored in String, you should parse Integer from it
                miles = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());

                km = miles * 1.609344f;

                textField2.setText(String.format("%f", km));
            }else if(event.getSource() == textField2){
                // Value form field stored in String, you should parse Integer from it
                km = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());

                miles = km / 1.609344f;

                textField1.setText(String.format("%f", km));        
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong value", "Input error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, so confuse...I'm really beginner in java programming, so can you more explain? what do I need to remove and add for result? 
I want to input mile and press enter, the result will be kilometer.
the other case too.

Comment: @Young remove this line textField1.addActionListener(handler); Additional information in updated answer.

Comment: I removed the line  textField1.addActionListener(handler).
Also, change TextfieldHangler, 
However, still when I put the input and press Enter, nothing happened.......

Comment: Finally, I find and make sure.
If I put mile and press Enter, the output is kilometer.
other side too.

However, when I put the kilometer, the changing mile is wrong.
Can you tell me what's wrong?
I put the  textField1.addActionListener(new TextFieldHandler(){
    });
 
 textField2.addActionListener(new TextFieldHandler(){
    }); next to container.add( textField2 ); line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a single frame and a single button, I would suggest to set the following line:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton);
```

You can set a default button on each frame you control, the button you set in this method, will automatically listen to enter and invoke your actionPerformed.

You can also use a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) and extend the functionality for your button in this case or in future exercises or projects.

Hope it helps.

All the best... and happy coding :)

Comment: How can I frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton); apply in this code? put in the Grid1 class?

Comment: Since you're invoking your method in the same frame, just replace frame by "this", this refers to the same class you're working. So:

Comment: Since you are writing all the logic inside your frame class, just replace "frame" by the reserved word "this". This refers to the class you're working in this moment, since your Grid1 extends JFrame, using this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton); would be enough :)

Comment: I write this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton); in this grid1, however, it shows submitButton is cannot be resolved to a variable. what's wrong??

Comment: Your variable name for your button is "submit", I used as an example "submitButton", so then replace "submitButton" by "submit" which is the name of your button.

Comment: Finally, I find and make sure.
If I put mile and press Enter, the output is kilometer.
other side too.

However, when I put the kilometer, the changing mile is wrong.
Can you tell me what's wrong?
I put the  textField1.addActionListener(new TextFieldHandler(){
    });
 
 textField2.addActionListener(new TextFieldHandler(){
    }); next to container.add( textField2 ); line.